# Tooltip on Live LineChart

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I found many examples how to add Tooltip on a LineChart but no information or example how to add Tooltip on Live LineChart.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private Series series2;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        //-- Chart
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis)
        {
            // Override to remove symbols on each data point
            @Override
            protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item)
            {
            }
        };

        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

        //-- Chart Series
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        series2 = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series2.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().addAll(series, series2);

        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sc));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        //-- Prepare Executor Services
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        //-- Prepare Timeline
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // add a item of random data to queue
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                dataQ2.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(200);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    //-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;

            Data data = new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove());

            series.getData().add(data);

            data.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> arg0, Node arg1,
                    Node arg2)
                {
                    Tooltip t = new Tooltip(data.getYValue().toString() + '\n' + data.getXValue());
                    Tooltip.install(arg2, t);
                    data.nodeProperty().removeListener(this);
                }
            });

            if (dataQ2.isEmpty())
                break;
            series2.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData, dataQ2.remove()));
        }
        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }

        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series2.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series2.getData().remove(0, series2.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }

        // update
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

This is the result that I would like to create:

[image]

If possible I to set setCreateSymbols(false);

Comment: again, the code is mostly unrelated to your problem and missing any hint as to what you tried ... why wouldn't the examples with static data don't suit dynamic data?

Comment: @kleopatra I added the code that I tested but when I run the code I don't see Tooltip.

Comment: okay, see now: but that's unrelated to the dynamic nature, it's related to not having a symbol (aka: node) on the data - so there is nothing to attach the tooltip to

Comment: @kleopatra I found may example with static LineChart data. But looks like for this I need deep knowledge?

Comment: in your shoes I would first try to get tooltips on a static lineChart without symbols: you may need to set it on the series and update its content with position (never tried, so don't know). Once you solve the static problem, go ahead with the dynamic data: the addition problem to solve would be that the data moves quite quickly below the mouse, you'll need to address that (first think about the usabillity)

Comment: btw: where's the screenshot from? It doesn't have symbols but is showing the tooltip - how did they do it?

Comment: @kleopatra this is a picture from html code. I just wanted to show how I would like to see the final result.

Comment: Why is your chart overriding the `dataItemAdded(...)` method?

Comment: @James_D I get the code example from here https://community.oracle.com/thread/2413087 According the author: 1) How and why I override the dataItemAdded() method. I did it this way rather than via CSS because of performance, this will be much faster which is important if you are trying to animate like you are. In most cases CSS method will be fine but for this case overriding will be faster. I found out how by looking at the source code for AreaChart which is available OpenSource. I had the advantage of having written most of this code in the first place ;-)

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't do it that way. As @kleopatra points out, it means you are not getting any nodes set on the chart, which means there is nothing to which to attach the tooltip. I would get rid of that overridden method and change the node in the usual way (if you want to). Get it working using the API as it's intended to be used; [only worry about performance if you have evidence it's a problem](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson).

Comment: @James_D Can you show me some working example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a regular `AreaChart` instead of the anonymous subclass you are using (i.e. don't override the `dataAddedItem(...)` method). That method creates a default node to display for the data point if none already exists (this is a huge violation of separating data from presentation, imho, but there's nothing we can do about that...); you obviously need a graphic there to attach the tooltip to.

Once the data point has a node, you don't need to listen to the changes, so in your `addDataToSeries()` method, remove the listener and just replace it with

```
        Tooltip t = new Tooltip(data.getYValue().toString() + '\n' + data.getXValue());
        Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), t);
```

Or, just create your own graphic, attach a tooltip to it, and pass it to `data.setNode(...);`.

You will still have a general usability problem; I don't see how the user is going to hover over a data point in the chart when everything is flying by at 5 units per second. And even if they could, by the time the tooltip appeared the points would have moved, so the values would be incorrect...

Update:

Just for fun, I tried this:

```
    ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLocationInScene = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();

    sc.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, evt -> {
        if (! tooltip.isShowing()) {
            mouseLocationInScene.set(new Point2D(evt.getSceneX(), evt.getSceneY()));
        }
    });

    tooltip.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if (mouseLocationInScene.isNull().get()) {
            return "" ;
        }
        double xInXAxis = xAxis.sceneToLocal(mouseLocationInScene.get()).getX() ;
        double x = xAxis.getValueForDisplay(xInXAxis).doubleValue();
        double yInYAxis = yAxis.sceneToLocal(mouseLocationInScene.get()).getY() ;
        double y = yAxis.getValueForDisplay(yInYAxis).doubleValue() ;
        return String.format("[%.3f, %.3f]", x, y);
    }, mouseLocationInScene, xAxis.lowerBoundProperty(), xAxis.upperBoundProperty(),
    yAxis.lowerBoundProperty(), yAxis.upperBoundProperty()));

    Tooltip.install(sc, tooltip);
```

This sets a tooltip on the chart that updates both as you move the mouse and as the chart scrolls below. This combines ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562195/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-chart-space/28563344#28563344) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585330/tooltip-how-to-get-mouse-coordinates-that-triggered-the-tip).

Comment: plus +1 - not least for 1000% ack of the "huge violation"! It's incredibly annoying... BTW: no need for a node on the data point (it only has if symbols are shown), instead install the tooltip on the series and update its text

Comment: :-) alternatives are good, and as always I like your binding magic. The tooltip per-chart gets into trouble if there's more than one series

Answer (score 2):

Answering an implicit part of the question: how to install a tooltip that's showing the current x/y values if there are no symbols, that is the data has no node? And only for a static chart (or one that's reasonable slow changing such that the location/value of the tooltip wouldn't make sense while showing)

There are several problems to solve

- the tooltip has to be installed on the node of the series: same trick as with installing on the node of the data - done in a listener to its nodeProperty, only then can we be certain that the node is created
- it's text has to be updated when showing: done onShowing (note a [bug in the setter](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40080), so we need to use the property directly)
- it's text should be related to the mouse location of its triggering event: as there doesn't seem to be [any api that allows access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28585330/203657) to the triggering event we have to keep track of that location ourselves, below in a mouse-moved that stores the current mouse screen location in the properties of the tooltip
- coordinate transformation from mouse-coordinates to "world" chart-coordinates

An example:

```
public class ToolTipOnChartSeries extends Application {

    private static final Object MOUSE_TRIGGER_LOCATION = "tooltip-last-location";

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Double>> getChartData() {
        double javaValue = 17.56;
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Double>> answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Series<String, Double> java = new Series<String, Double>();
        java.setName("java");
        Tooltip t = new Tooltip();
        t.setOnShowing(e -> {
            Point2D screen = (Point2D) t.getProperties().get(MOUSE_TRIGGER_LOCATION);
            if (screen == null) return;
            XYChart chart = java.getChart();
            double localX = chart.getXAxis().screenToLocal(screen).getX();
            double localY = chart.getYAxis().screenToLocal(screen).getY();
            Object xValue = chart.getXAxis().getValueForDisplay(localX);
            Object yValue = chart.getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(localY);
            t.textProperty().set("x/y: " + t.getX() + " / " + t.getY() 
                    + "\n localX " + localX + "/" + xValue 
                    + "\n localY " + localY + "/" + yValue 

                    );
        });
        java.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>()
        { 
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> arg0, Node arg1,
                Node node)
            {
                Tooltip.install(node, t);
                node.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
                    Point2D screen = new Point2D(e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    t.getProperties().put(MOUSE_TRIGGER_LOCATION, screen);
                });
                java.nodeProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 2011; i < 2021; i++) {
            // adding a tooltip to the data node
            final XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(i), javaValue);
            java.getData().add(data);
            javaValue = javaValue + Math.random() - .5;
        }
        answer.addAll(java); //, c, cpp);
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        lineChart.setData(getChartData());
        lineChart.setTitle("speculations");
        primaryStage.setTitle("LineChart example");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(lineChart);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root)); //, 400, 250));
        primaryStage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ToolTipOnChartSeries.class
            .getName());
}
```

BTW: fully agree with James on the useability issue: data racing across the chart can't really be handled by a tooltip on the data/series. If you really need that, you'll have to implement some custom marker (like f.i. a vertical line) that's added on a mouse gesture, keep that line sticky (aka: sync'ed to the moving x-values) to the data, and attach the tooltip to that line.

Comment: Ah, cross post with my update... also inspired partly by [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585330/tooltip-how-to-get-mouse-coordinates-that-triggered-the-tip). I just attached the tooltip to the chart though...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really got the problem you want to solve (simply adding a tooltip should be exactly the same) but if you want to "update" your tooltip with the livedata you could simply make a bind between the data and if the tooltip shouldn't update itself change the data of the tooltip in a Platform.runLater().

Comment: I added the Tooltip code. When I run the example nothing is displayed.

Comment: Maybe because you do a new Tooltip everytime the listener is activated.
Try to do one Tooltip and just change the value that is displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the code I need to modify. Can you show me code example?

Comment: `data.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> arg0, Node arg1,
                    Node arg2)
                {
                    Tooltip t = new Tooltip(data.getYValue().toString() + '\n' + data.getXValue());
                    Tooltip.install(arg2, t);
                    data.nodeProperty().removeListener(this);
                }
            });`
Here you are adding a new Tooltip everytime the changelistener activates.

Comment: But instead you should just set the Tooltip 1 Time and in the Changelistener you should say `t.setText(data.getYValue().toString() + '\n' + data.getXValue());`

Sorry comment was too long ^^

Comment: @Juce - no, the listener is activated exactly once per data element (it's removing itself)

Comment: Okey then, i don't know the Tooltip.install method but does it replaye the tooltip.show() method? Because i can't see it in there :P

Comment: why would install replace the show method, that's handled by the collaborator which actually triggers the showing - hint: java doc is there for reading ;-) Please read and understand the code - now, at last - provided by OP instead of playing guessing games. As I mentioned in a comment to the question: the problem might be that there _is no_ node on the data in a symbolless chart (because it doesn't have a node)