# How to get mouse position in chart-space

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How can one obtain the mouse position on an `XYChart<Number,Number>`, in chart-space coordinates?

Here is an example of my attempt using `NumberAxis.getValueForDisplay()`:

```
public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Axis<Number> xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    Axis<Number> yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    XYChart<Number,Number> chart = new AreaChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

    Pane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().add(chart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    chart.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setTitle("" +
            xAxis.getValueForDisplay(event.getX()) + ",  " +
            yAxis.getValueForDisplay(event.getY())
        );
    });

    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

but when I run this the coordinates I get have an offset error of about 10.6, -4.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing the `x` and `y` coordinates relative to the chart to the `getValueForDisplay(...)` methods. You need the coordinates relative to the actual axes. (The `xAxis` will be offset from the edge of the chart to allow horizontal room for the `yAxis`, and possibly other padding, and vice-versa.)

To do this, get the coordinates of the mouse event relative to the scene and transform them to the coordinate systems of the axes:

```
chart.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {

    Point2D mouseSceneCoords = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
    double x = xAxis.sceneToLocal(mouseSceneCoords).getX();
    double y = yAxis.sceneToLocal(mouseSceneCoords).getY();

    primaryStage.setTitle("" +
        xAxis.getValueForDisplay(x) + ",  " +
        yAxis.getValueForDisplay(y)
    );
});
```