# How to translate the plot area of a Line Chart in JavaFX for the hover labels to become visible?

Tags: javafx, linechart

In my JavaFX application I have a LineChart with multiple `XYChart.Series` whose nodes, when hovered, show a label containing the value.

The chart and the Y axis need to have the following configuration so that the range could adapt dynamically according to the values ascribed:

```
axaCote.forceZeroInRangeProperty().setValue(false);
axaCote.autoRangingProperty().setValue(true);
areaChart.setAnimated(true);
```

This is the class creating the hover labels:

```
class HoveredThresholdNode extends StackPane {
        HoveredThresholdNode(int value) {
            setPrefSize(15, 15);

            final Label label = createDataThresholdLabel(value);

            setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    getChildren().setAll(label);
                    setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
                    toFront();
                    toFront();
                }
            });
            setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    getChildren().clear();
                    setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
                }
            });
        }

        private Label createDataThresholdLabel(int value) {
            final Label label = new Label(value + "");
            label.setTranslateY(25);
            label.getStyleClass().addAll("default-color0", "chart-line-symbol", "chart-series-line");
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20; -fx-font-weight: bold;");

            label.setTextFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            label.setMinSize(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE, Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            return label;
        }
    }
```

In my outer class I have this code:

```
XYChart.Data<String, Number> nod = nod = new XYChart.Data<>(convertLocalDate(auxData,"yyyy-MM-dd","dd-MM-yyyy"), cota);
nod.setNode(new HoveredThresholdNode(cota));
```

However, due to this configuration my labels are not visible:

[image]

Is there any way to translate the plot area, preserving the `autoRangingProperty`, so that they get visible?

Comment: How are you making the labels in the first place?

Comment: @James_D, you are right, I edited my post.

Comment: I think a regular tooltip has logic to make sure it is displayed in a sensible place. Have you tried using a built-in tooltip and using CSS to style it? Otherwise you are going to have to write the logic to look up the bounds of the parent node, etc, and figure out appropriate values for `translateX` and `translateY` accordingly.

Comment: Could you please a suggest an example for doing this? I have tried some code found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28566659/5491105), but no Tooltip appears in my chart.

Comment: I don't have any chart example to work with. If you want to create a [MCVE] then it would give me something to work from. But you should be able just to get the node for each data point, create a tooltip whose text is bound to the value of the data, and call `Tooltip.install(node, tooltip)`.